# Rails3 error using form_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I generated model and views using scaffold generate command, but after generation this problem appear...

Showing `/home/coderx/development/avioapp/app/views/plains/_form.html.erb` where line `#1` raised:

```
undefined method `define_attribute_methods' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for @plain do |f| %>
2:   <% if @plain.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@plain.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this plain from being saved:</h2>
```

Comment: Is @plain set up appropriately in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Yeap, it was a problem in Controller, I have messed up something when was using git branches.. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this type of error. In my case it was due to some **reserve keywords** (as table field).

Though you have found your solution but I think it might help others :)